# after clone slider doing wrong direction

Tags: javascript, slider, infinite-loop

I have need loop slider like below snippet

http://output.jsbin.com/ufoceq/8/

my code is below

```js
$.fn.Wcoursel = function (options) {

   
  var element = $('.wcoursel'),
      items   = element.find('.item'),
      len     = items.length,
      
      current = 1,  /* the current item we're looking */
      
      first   = items.filter(':first'),
      last    = items.filter(':last'),
      
      triggers = $('a'),
      $width = element.width(),
      $single_image_width = $width / 3;
        // element.find('.item').css('width', $single_image_width);
        //    element.find('.inner-coursel').css('width', $single_image_width*len);
    
  
  /* 1. Cloning first and last item */
  first.before(last.clone(true)); 
  last.after(first.clone(true)); 
  
  /* 2. Set button handlers */
  triggers.on('click', function() {
    
    if (element.is(':not(:animated)')) {
     
        var cycle = false,
            delta = (this.id === "prev")? -1 : 1;
            /* in the example buttons have id "prev" or "next" */  
    
        element.find('.inner-coursel').animate({ left: "+=" + (-100 * delta) }, function() {
      
            current += delta;
       
            /** 
             * we're cycling the slider when the the value of "current" 
             * variable (after increment/decrement) is 0 or when it exceeds
             * the initial element length
             */          
            cycle = !!(current === 0 || current > len);
       
            if (cycle) {
                /* we switched from image 1 to 4-cloned or 
                   from image 4 to 1-cloned */
                current = (current === 0)? len : 1; 
                element.find('.inner-coursel').css({left:  -100 * current });
            }
        });   
     }
    
  });

}
```

```css
  .wcoursel>div {
            transition: all 0.25s ease;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
        }
        
        .wcoursel {
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px green dotted;
   margin: 30px 0 0 150px;
   /* usually an «overflow:hidden» is set here */
}
         .wcoursel .inner-coursel
        {
           white-space: nowrap;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -100px;
   margin: 0; padding: 0;  
        }

        .item label {
    font-size: 28px;
        }
        
        .wcoursel .item {
          display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 96px;
   height: 96px;
                background: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
   white-space: normal;
   padding: 2px
        }

        .wcoursel a{  
         font: 10px "Courier New";
  border: 1px #d8d8d8 dotted;
  color: #626262;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px -150px 0 150px;
        }
        .navigation-coursel {
    margin: 103px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wcoursel" class="wcoursel">
        <div class="inner-coursel" style="">
            <div class="item">
               <label>1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                  <label>2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                  <label>3</label>
            </div>
          
            


        </div>
        <div class="navigation-coursel">
            <a class="nav-control" data-action="prev" id="prev">Prev</a>
            <a class="nav-control" data-action="next" id="next">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wcoursel.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
         $('#wcoursel').Wcoursel();
         });
     

    </script>
```

when loop is finish then after(after clone) when i press on next button then all slider moving in wrong direction.
Can you please help how can handle this.